# Zurb Foundation - Abide validation won't trigger

Tags: javascript, html, validation, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm trying to get Foundation's Abide validation working with a simple static form, but I'm not getting any errors or response from it. I'm expecting to see **data-invalid** attributes added to the invalid input elements, but they remain unchanged.

I've included Modernizr, jQuery and as far as I can see from the Zurb docs, all the dependencies that Abide requires. I don't care about CSS right now, just want to be able to have Abide validate the form.

Most of the following code has been taken from the Zurb Foundation docs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Abide test...</title>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form data-abide id="contact">
    <div class="name-field">
        <label>Your name
            <small>required</small>
            <input type="text" required>
        </label>
        <small class="error">Name is required and must be a string.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="email-field">
        <label>Email
            <small>required</small>
            <input type="email" required>
        </label>
        <small class="error">An email address is required.</small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foundation.abide.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with the above? All the .js files are loading, no 404 errors in Chrome console.

Comment: I noticed that Abide does not even add novalidate="novalidate" like it does on the Foundation Abide documentation page example. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html

Comment: Even this jsfiddle example by someone else: http://jsfiddle.net/R9T7y/ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've created my own fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/josefvanniekerk/rz0nh725/1/, still no validation, and I think I have followed Zurb's documentation to the book...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this piece of CSS is required:

```css
meta.foundation-data-attribute-namespace {
    font-family: false;
}
```

Foundation 5 seems to read its global namespace from the font-family property of `meta.foundation-data-attribute-namespace` (that's kinda weird).

Answer (score 0):

**Foundation.css is required.** When I forked your fiddle and simply added foundation.css to external resources, data-invalid appends as you'd expect.

Comment: Looking at foundation.abide.js, I'm not sure why it would break on that but it does nonetheless. When I have time, I'll have to test out other JS functions and see if they break as well; perhaps an issue needs to be created for it. I wasn't even expecting that to happen either, just figured I'd set it up like I usually did. Pretty weird requirement.